# How to call a HEAD request which returns an empty response from JAVA client?

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to call a API which returns 100 as response code and empty response.

```
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpHead;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;

import java.net.URI;

public class SampleController {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {
            String urlStr = "http://localhost:8080/headrequest";
            HttpHead request = new HttpHead(new URI(urlStr));
            request.addHeader("Expect", "100-continue");

            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
            client.execute(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the error:

```
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8080: The target server failed to respond
Aug 19, 2020 3:36:26 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8080
Aug 19, 2020 3:36:26 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8080: The target server failed to respond
Aug 19, 2020 3:36:26 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8080
Aug 19, 2020 3:36:26 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing request to {}->http://localhost:8080: The target server failed to respond
Aug 19, 2020 3:36:26 PM org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {}->http://localhost:8080
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: localhost:8080 failed to respond
Exception: localhost:8080 failed to respond
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.application.controller.SampleController.main(SampleController.java:20)
```

But from the servers access logs. I can confirm that the API has executed and the server returned a 100 response code.

`"HEAD /headrequest HTTP/1.1" 100`

So, from the above error I understand that the apaches HttpClinet is not configured to terminate connection once the server sends response code **100** and still expecting the server to send response.

My question here is, are there any java libs that handle the termination of HEAD request once it receives 100.

I did try googling this but was unsuccessful to determine any solution :(

**Edit 1:**  I tried with `HttpURLConnection`

```
private static void testing() throws Exception {
        HttpURLConnection urlConn = null;

        try {
            String urlStr = "http://localhost:8080/headrequest";

            URL url = new URL(urlStr);
            urlConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");

            
            urlConn.setRequestProperty("Expect", "100-continue");

            if (urlConn.getResponseCode() != 100) {
                System.out.println("Miss match in the response: " + urlConn.getResponseCode());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Below is the error response:

```
Exception: Unexpected end of file from server
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:851)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:877)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:877)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:848)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:877)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:877)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1593)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1498)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at com.application.controller.SampleController.testing(SampleController.java:44)
    at com.application.controller.SampleController.main(SampleController.java:28)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.1.1) says

> A client MUST NOT generate a 100-continue expectation in a request
> that does not include a message body.

Hence its probably appacheclient which expects to send message body once 100 response received, throws exception as the connection closed.

If its not mandatory to use apacheclient, below simple code will read just the response line with 100 status code and close the connection.

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class Requestor
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Socket s;
        BufferedReader br;
        BufferedWriter bw;
        String a;
        String response;
        try{
        s=new Socket("localhost",8080);
        br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(s.getInputStream())));
        bw=new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(s.getOutputStream())));

        bw.write("HEAD /headrequest HTTP/1.1");
        bw.newLine();
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();
        response="";
        
        a=br.readLine();
        System.out.println(a);
        
        s.close();
        
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this is understandable. But, in java how to check if the server has return 100. BTW thanks for your response.

Comment: @Finnismissing I have updated the answer to include code to read status response from from server.